# A data set to distinguish man from woman?

Tags: dataset

Is there a set and/or a model that is available freely in the Internet that can tell man from woman based on input image?

Comment: [IMDB-WIKI – 500k+ face images with age and gender labels](https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/cvl/rrothe/imdb-wiki/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [deepdetect](https://www.deepdetect.com/) which provides image classification functionality over API.

There is a gender classification model available on the [models page](https://www.deepdetect.com/applications/model/). I have used it without problems before.